# How can I make sure that the image captured using camera in ReactJS is less than 1MB?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using 'react-camera-pro' to capture an image from Camera in React, how can I make sure that the image captured using the camera will be less than 1MB?
Eventually, I have to convert it in a byte-array and send it to an API.

Comment: you would have to compress it if it isnt. Look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956281/best-way-to-compress-an-image-javascript-react-web-app